# Dynamic event handler based on a condition in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I know you can have a different template that uses a different event handler based on a condition but is there a way to make just the event handler name dynamic in knockout?

for example:

```
<button data-bind="event : { EventToUse() : SomeMethod }"></button>
```

And have a method like this:

```
self.EventToUse = function(){
    return 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
};
```

The above syntax for binding is invalid so it's not a solution but just a sketch of my aim

Once again I know about having something like this:

```
self.TemplateToUse = function(){
    return 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? 'touch-Template' : 'desktop-Template';
};
```

and binding that to the container where templates load.

I am after finding out whether this can be done using less key strokes.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The `event` binding accepts an object, and that object can be constructed dynamically.

```
<button data-bind="event: TouchOrClick(SomeMethod)"></button>
```

The method:

```
self.TouchOrClick= function(method) {
    return 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? 
        { 'touchstart' : method } : { 'click' : method };
};
```